# Magento & Wordpress Integration

Tags: css, wordpress

Ive been reading up on all the various ways to attack this! The closest thing to the layout I'm trying to achieve and the way it works is this.

http://www.flatspot.com/journal/blog/

I had a look through the source and couldn't work out the method of intergration i was hoping someone could put me in the right direction for achieving this kind of usability & styling.

Check the home page they pull a feed too from the blog this i would also like to achieve.

Any input greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to say, but your question is waaay too broad in scope. Better to try things and then ask more specific questions (after searching to see if they've been answered). Also, there is no single best solution to your problem (another reason to close). For a general question such as this, it's best to head over to the [official Magento community forums](http://community.magento.com).

Comment: Well this has been quite a useless experience, its hardly that broad I'm asking how to achieve whats been done above not basic integration answered everywhere else. Im looking for a direction not an answer i don't have the time to waste on "trying things".  

There maybe no single best solution, (I'm sure that goes for 60% of questions here too) but I've yet to see any solutions posted here except for the same recommend plugin!

Comment: Rather than being a useless experience, you've learned that questions and answers on the Stack platform are intentionally limited in scope. This is driven in part by the aim of the platform to provide a canonical answer store *for more than just the original inquirer.* Also, if you have "no time to waste on 'trying things'" then I suspect you'll have a rough go of Magento development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend fishpig http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

Its a really powerful module and also has in depth documentation.